# How to wait until method complete in C#?

Tags: c#

I have this C# code, it works but it won't wait until the method completed

```
foreach (var listBoxItem in visualListBox1.Items)
{
    lblCursor.Text = "Processing.. " + listBoxItem;
    Thread t = new Thread(() => extract_group(listBoxItem.ToString()));
    t.IsBackground = false; 
    t.Name = "Group Scrapper";
    t.Start();
}
```

How to wait until `extract_group` method is done before moving to the next `listBoxItem`?

I used `t.join()` but it made the UI unresponsive.

Comment: What does extract_group look like, this look a job for `async`/`await` and not `Thread`. Also tip, this is not javascript you should use the appropriate case and conventions for methods

Comment: This question has no simple answer. You could just run the whole loop in a separate thread. But I'd recommend you familiarize yourself with the `Task` class and `async`/`await`. You will end up with cleaner code that is easier to synchronize.

Comment: please replace this code : `string Value = listBoxItem.ToString(); Thread t = new Thread(() => extract_group(Value));` to see the result. I think there should be another problem in `extract_group` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using async/await helps you to not block main thread.

```
public async Task ExtractGroupAsync()
{
   ... (logic of the method)
   ... (you should use async methods here as well with await before executing those methods)
}
```

You execute this "ExtractGroup" task like:

```
var example = await ExtractGroupAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes GUI unresponsive, because you are on GUI thread. Run whole code, in separate thread.
Note: when you want to access GUI elements from another thread, you should use invoke, for example:

```
t.Invoke(() => t.Name = "Group Scrapper");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with *Thread* I recommend using a [WaitHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx) e.g. [AsyncManualResetEvent Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.asyncmanualresetevent?view=visualstudiosdk-2017). This approach allows to make a thread wait without blocking CPU (e.g. spinlock). 
Your provided example would become:

```
private static AsyncManualResetEvent mre = new AsyncManualResetEvent(false, true);
public async Task DoSomethingAsync(...)
{
  foreach (var listBoxItem in visualListBox1.Items)
  {
    lblCursor.Text = "Processing.. " + listBoxItem;
    Thread t = new Thread(() => ExtractGroup(listBoxItem.ToString()));
    t.IsBackground = false; 
    t.Name = "Group Scrapper";
    t.Start();

    // Wait for signal to proceed without blocking resources
    await mre.WaitAsync();
  }
}

private void ExtractGroup(string groupName)
{
  // Do something ...

  // Signal handle to release all waiting threads (makes them continue).
  // Subsequent calls to Set() or WaitOne() won't show effects until Rest() was called
  mre.Set();

  // Reset handle to make future call of WaitOne() wait again.
  mre.Reset();
}
```

Another solution would be to go with the [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) and use *[Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx)* instead of *Thread*:

```
public async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
  foreach (var listBoxItem in visualListBox1.Items)
  {
    lblCursor.Text = "Processing.. " + listBoxItem;

    // Wait for signal to proceed without blocking resources
    await Task.Run(() => ExtractGroup(listBoxItem.ToString()));
  }
}
```

The issue with your code sample is, that you are currently on the main thread, the UI thread. Calling Thread.Join() does what you think it does: it blocks the waiting thread until the running thread completes. But as mentioned, the waiting thread is the UI thread, so the UI becomes unresponsive and can even deadlock in some scenario. When you use [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index) your invocations become asynchronous and hence awaitable  without blocking the UI thread.

Comment: Won't both examples close on `listBoxItem`?

Comment: @JohnWu The examples are waiting until one item is completed and then proceeds with the next item.

Comment: @JohnWu I am sorry. I think I didn't get you. Could you please explain what you are meanig?